# pjsip (pjsua2) - opus codec for windows

Tags: c++, c, pjsip, opus

is it possible to build [pjsip](https://www.pjsip.org/) with [opus-codec](https://opus-codec.org/) for **windows** as dll?
I built pjsua2.dll alone but seems no way to use opus with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded opus and pjsip , opened pjsip from visual studio solution, added opus projects to solution and made reference to them from libpjpproject, then build it using this link [link](https://github.com/AaronReynoldsUK/PJSIP-PJSUA2-CSharp/blob/master/build-it-yourself.md)